# python : how to parse zipped xml file?

Tags: python

My code looks like

```
def read_zip_file():
    import zipfile
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.expanduser('~/Downloads/tmp/me.zip'))
    for filename in [ 'myfile.xml' ]:
        print filename
        try :
            data = get_proposal_data_map(zf.read(filename))
            print data
        except:
            logging.error('error - ' + str(sys.exc_info()))
```

This spits out the xml as regular file. Now I have a existing code, which given a path parses XML as

```
try:
    tree = etree.parse(path)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for child in root:
              # do things with XML
```

**Question**

How can I `parse` a `zipped XML (myfile.xml.zip)` as regular `XML` file?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here as you seem to know how to unzip a file and how to parse an xml file.  Wouldn't you just put those two steps together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just read the zip file into a variable and then use

```
root = etree.fromstring(xmlstr)
```